# use dynamic variable in route tag vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I use this template for breadcrumb:

```
<route>
{
name: "educations-view-id-tab", 
meta: {
pageTitle: 'Educations',
breadcrumb: [
{
title: 'List',
to:{ name: 'educations' },
disabled:false
},
{
title: 'View',
disabled:true
},
],
}
}
</route>
```

how can I use variable in the pageTitle?
I use vue 3 and vuetify and use this route tag in breadcrumb component
example:

```
<route>
{
name: "educations-view", 
meta: {
pageTitle: route.params.slug, // example dynamic route
breadcrumb: [
{
title: 'List',
to:{ name: 'educations' },
disabled:false
}
],
}
}
</route>
```

example: I want use this code and use route params in breadcrumb

```
<route>
{
name: "educations-view-id-tab", 
meta: {
pageTitle: route.params.slug, // example dynamic route
}
}
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in the `pageTitle` of your breadcrumb, you can use Vue's string interpolation syntax, which allows you to embed expressions within a string by wrapping them in curly braces `{}`. In your case, you can replace the static page title with a dynamic one based on the `route.params.slug` value, like this:

```
<route>
{
  name: "educations-view-id-tab", 
  meta: {
    pageTitle: `Educations - ${route.params.slug}`, // dynamic page title using string interpolation
    breadcrumb: [
      {
        title: 'List',
        to:{ name: 'educations' },
        disabled:false
      },
      {
        title: 'View',
        disabled:true
      },
    ],
  }
}
</route>
```

Comment: tnx, but it's not worked and we can't use js code in the route tag